# Transparent trapezoidal buttons with border and centered text

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, css-transforms

I'm designing a site where trapezoids are crucial. I'm using the following code to achieve the effect I'm looking for, but am having issues with it: http://jsfiddle.net/9n9uh6f6/9/

The biggest problems are the mouseover area (because I'm using perspective transforms, the clickable area is skewed) and centering text within the shape.

Other than using perspective transforms, how can I make a shape that does the following:

1. Trapezoid with a colored border and transparent interior.
2. Trapezoid that can change color when a user hovers over it.
3. Trapezoid that houses text in the center of the shape.

Here's the CSS I'm using:

```
.prodcaptions {
  width:136px;
  height: 85px;
  position:relative;
  left:10%;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  text-align:center;
  letter-spacing: 1.6px;
  color: #000;
}
.prodcaptions:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  border-radius:1px;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 3px #27628e;
  top:-5%;
  bottom:-11%;
  left:-1%;
  right:-5%;
  -webkit-transform:perspective(40em) rotateX(-45deg);
  transform:perspective(40em) rotateX(-45deg);
}

.prodcaptions a {
  z-index:999;
  position:relative;
  height: 85px;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can try with mapped coordinates?

Comment: maybe http://jsfiddle.net/9n9uh6f6/10/

Answer (score 3):

For this case, it would be better to use a skew transform to produce the shape than a rotation with perspective.

We can achieve the shape by using two pseudo-elements skewed in opposite directions and then position one at the left corner and the other at the right corner. Since only the pseudo-elements are skewed and not the main container, the text remains in its expected place (at center-middle).

This shape can (a) support dynamic width (b) have a colored border with transparent background (c) have the text in the center of the shape and (d) support change of background color when hovered on.

```css
.trapezoid {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  color: #27628e;
  border-top: 2px solid #27628e;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #27628e;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1.6px;
  margin: 15px 250px; /* Just for demo */
}
.trapezoid:after,
.trapezoid:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: -2px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.trapezoid:before {
  left: 0px;
  border-left: 2px solid #27628e;
  border-top: 2px solid #27628e;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: skew(10deg);
}
.trapezoid:after {
  right: 0px;
  border-right: 2px solid #27628e;
  border-top: 2px solid #27628e;
  transform-origin: right bottom;
  transform: skew(-10deg);
}
.trapezoid:hover,
.trapezoid:hover:after,
.trapezoid:hover:before {
  background: #27628e;
  color: white;
}

/* Just for demo */

body {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, aliceblue, powderblue);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<a href='#' class="trapezoid">Click Me!!!</a>
```

---

You could also create the same shape using SVG and the angled sides look a tad more smoother while using SVG. The below snippet currently works only for a fixed size container. It should not be an issue as the code in question also has fixed dimensions.

```css
.vector {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: -webkit-calc(100px * 1.36);
  width: calc(100px * 1.36);
  line-height: 100px;
  margin: 0px auto; /* Just for demo */
}
svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%:
}
polygon {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke: steelblue;
}
.vector a {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1.6px;
  color: steelblue;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.vector:hover polygon {
  fill: steelblue;
}
.vector:hover a {
  color: white;
}

/* Just for demo */
body{
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, aliceblue, powderblue);
}
```

```html
<div class='vector'>
  <svg viewBox='0 0 136 100' preserveaspectratio='none'>
    <polygon points='1,2 18,98 118,98 135,2' />
  </svg>
  <a href='#'>Click Me!!!</a>
</div>
```